# script to determine the same center point of many circles with differents trajectories

Tags: python-3.x

I have many circles trajectories in my plan; those circles have the same center.
How could I determine this center point with python script?

```
import random, import numpy as np, import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def find_circle_center():##script I need to know 

 x,y=[],[] #make circle center with somme error 
 _circle = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[10, 0],[0, 10]], 1)[0] 
 circle_x = _circle[0] 
 circle_y = _circle[1] 
 # angle 
 alpha = np.linspace(0,2 * pi,10001) 
 # many radius trajectory 
 for radius in [1,10,100,200,300,400,500,600]:
     aux = random.randint(0,10000)
     alpha_aux = np.concatenate([alpha[aux:,],alpha[:aux,]]) #randomize angle array  
     _x = radius * np.cos(alpha_aux) + circle_x   
     _y = radius * np.sin(alpha_aux) + circle_y   
     x.append(_x)   
     y.append(_y) 

x,y=np.array(x),np.array(y) #now i have points of circles trajectories. 

_xc,_yc = [],[] 
  #this loop is to know after how many points will converge to the good answer
 for j in range(2,1001,1):   
     xc,yc = find_circle_center(x[:,:j].ravel(), x[:,:j].ravel())   
     _xc.append(xc)   
     _yc.append(yc) 

_xc,_yc = np.array(_xc),np.array(_yc)

plt.plot(range(2,1001,1),np.sqrt(_xc**2 +_yc**2)) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A circle's center is also its center of mass, [which can be computed as the average of the points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points) on that circle. If you have a bunch of points that represent a circle of some sort, just average them together, and that point will be the best approximation of the center.

Comment: This is true if circles are complete. But not for incomplete circles; example: arc in angle theta, you canot find the center like this but by fit yes. This is why in my code i variate the number of points in each estimation to find either the angle of best resolution, or the number of points in each circle for best resolution. Now i try to investigate Hough transformations.